# Paste date on input type="datetime-local" from clipboard

Tags: javascript, html, angular, datetime

I want paste date on input type="datetime-local" from string formatted "YYYY-MM-DD HH:mm:ss" saved on clipboard.

I've used paste event on input

```
 <input (paste)="onPaste($event)" max="2100-01-01T00:00" type="datetime-local"/>

 onPaste(event: ClipboardEvent) {
        let clipboardData = event.clipboardData ;
        let pastedText = clipboardData.getData('text');
        alert("Pasted" + pastedText);
    }
```

But it doesn't work.
See full example [here](https://jsfiddle.net/crakdelpol/9xmqz6e7/3/)
I've read doc on https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/HTML/Element/input/datetime-local.

Anyone can help me?

Comment: I'd suggest you use  https://material.angular.io/components/datepicker/overview#choosing-a-date-implementation-and-date-format-settings for this. all this datetime inputs are still in an alpha state and really buggy in chrome if you use them in a none english format. Probably not the answer you want but I spend a lot of time on this date/time format inputs and realized it is not worth the effort yet.

Comment: You should add more information. What browser? Explain what happens and what you would expect instead. "*it doesn't work*" is not enough.

Comment: I fear it is by design from Chrome... I you right click on this input you'll see there is no "paste" option on this input, while it is for others. I'd follow the plugin advice here.

Comment: @str all browsers, when i paste date on input it don't fire paste event.

Comment: @MatteoPipitone It works as intended for me in both Firefox and Safari.